# DirectoryIndex not found on AliasMatch

Tags: regex, apache, mod-alias

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) I have this:

`AliasMatch "^/projects/(.+)" "/var/www/domain.name/$1/public"`

It should match only URLs like `../projects/project1`, not `../projects/` by itself.

When I go to say, `http://example.org/projects/project1/` it returns a `403 Forbidden`.The logs say because of:

`No matching DirectoryIndex found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`.

I've tried adding a `DirectoryIndex` explicitly in the vhosts but to no avail. I opened up the directory (`/var/www/domain.name/project1/public`) to be readable by everyone and now it just shows a directory listing of the folder I want. I can see that its going to the right folder and can see the index.html file but it just doesn't automatically get it like it should.

---

Summarized version of my VirtualHost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.name/www/public
    ServerName www.domain.name

    AliasMatch "^/projects/(.+)" "/var/www/domain.name/$1/public"

    ErrorDocument 401 err.php
    ErrorDocument 404 err.php
    ErrorDocument 500 err.php

    <Directory /var/www/domain.name>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I then set the permissions on the specific project folder to 755 I just get a directory listing. I've changed it back to 711.

All folders in /var/www/ are owned by username:www-data and have the permissions 711.

If I do a direct Alias to the folder i.e. `Alias /projects/<actual-project-name> /var/www/domain.name/<project-name>/public` it works.

Comment: Why do you mention /var/www/domain.name/project1/ when your aliasmatch will explicitly map to /var/www/domain.name/project1/public?

Comment: @covener I was just giving a general idea of what I have setup. I've updated it to avoid confusion. Thanks!

Comment: "No matching DirectoryIndex found" - means that you don't have an `index.html` (or whatever the specified directory index file is) in that directory.

Comment: @w3d `"...now it just shows a directory listing of the folder I want. I can see that its going to the right folder and can see the index.html file..."`. Everything is fine except it doesn't fetch the index file thats there, instead it just displays a directory listing (in which I can see the index file).

Comment: And presumably you also enabled `Indexes`? Your `AliasMatch` directive maps _all_ URLs that _start_ `/projects/<project>` to a single destination - is that intentional? Is `/var/www/domain.name/<project>/public` under the same document root? Add your `<VirtualHost>` to your question so we can have a better look.

Comment: @w3d Yeah, briefly, to see if it was actually pointing to the right directory. I'm not sure what you mean by a single destination; they all have they're own folder based on their name which is captured into `$1`. `domain.name/projects/<project> => /var/www/domain.name/<project>/public`, whereas `domain.name/projects/ => /var/www/domain.name/www/public` (essentially just accessing a php file in main site document root - I've stripped the .php extensions for files in the main site document root). I've added my VHost to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `AliasMatch "^/projects/(.+)" "/var/www/domain.name/$1/public"`

The problem with this is that *all* requests are mapped to a single URL - a directory. `AliasMatch` does not copy the trailing path onto the end of the target, unlike an `Alias`.

When you request `/projects/project1`, the alias naturally maps you to `/projects/public`. mod_dir (`DirectorySlash`) appends a trailing slash (since this is a valid directory), but the directory index is lost. The target file is literally just `/projects/public/` (a directory), as stated in the `AliasMatch` directive, not `/projects/public/index.html` as would seem to be required.

To make this work as intended (to be able to access all files *within* the "public" directory, eg. `index.php`) then you need a 2nd parenthesised subpattern, something like:

```
AliasMatch ^/projects/([^/]+)(.*) /var/www/domain.name/$1/public/$2
```